# Aligning elements side by side in HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, google-maps

I am working on a website(this is my first website as a developer) and I was wondering if someone could help me align these to items next to each other horizontally. I don't know how to code HTML so I am completely unfamiliar with this. For the most part when developing sites I go and make due with what is online to help but this instance I am with your help.

The site is using WordPress and this is going to be a page. With a table from W-P Table reloaded and a Google map.
Here is the code currently:

```
<p style="text-align: left;">[table id=4 /]<small></small></p><p style="text-align: right;">
<iframe src="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Avie's+SKi+Sports+100+Main+Street,+Westerly,+R+02891-2194&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.375316,-71.831092&amp;sspn=0.006948,0.016512&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;g=100+Main+Street,+Westerly,+R+02891-2194&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Avie's+SKi+Sports+100+Main+Street,+Westerly,+R+02891-2194&amp;hnear=&amp;radius=15000&amp;t=m&amp;ll=41.379063,-71.831102&amp;spn=0.015457,0.027466&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=lyrftr:m,9024240540147588029,41.375323,-71.831043&amp;output=embed" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="no" width="640" height="480"></iframe>
<small><a style="color: #0000ff; text-align: left;" href="http://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=embed&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=Avie%27s+SKi+Sports+100+Main+Street,+Westerly,+R+02891-2194&amp;aq=&amp;sll=41.375316,-71.831092&amp;sspn=0.006948,0.016512&amp;vpsrc=0&amp;g=100+Main+Street,+Westerly,+R+02891-2194&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=Avie%27s+SKi+Sports+100+Main+Street,+Westerly,+R+02891-2194&amp;hnear=&amp;radius=15000&amp;t=m&amp;ll=41.379063,-71.831102&amp;spn=0.015457,0.027466&amp;z=15&amp;iwloc=lyrftr:m,9024240540147588029,41.375323,-71.831043">View Larger Map</a></small></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically when you want to line something up side by side on a page, you have two options:

1. The old school way - Use Tables (If you are using a program like Dreamweaver, this should be fairly easy - Insert > Table)
2. The better way - Using CSS. This may be a little harder for you to deal with since you said you have no experiencing working with HTML and I am presuming CSS.

The CSS way would require you to create a stylesheet with two divisions (divs). Here's an example of some code that would do that:

```
<style>
 #col1{ width:300px; float:left;}
 #col2 { width:300px; float: right;}
</style>
```

The above code would go between your `<head></head>` tags. Then in the body of your page, you would simply call the two divs:

```
<div id="col1">YOUR CONTENT</div>
<div id="col2">YOUR CONTENT</div>
```

Comment: Is there any free alternative to Dreamweaver, or am I stuck with getting that or coding a style sheet. The problem is that this is just a page on a WordPress site and uses the WordPress theme's style sheet.

Comment: @Tom Believe it or not, you actually are already using some CSS.  The value of your style attributes is CSS.

Comment: Well I am using CSS but I didn't create that myself. Right now I am your common guy who goes in to the .css files and deletes until they figure out what something does and changes colors.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I tried to use the CSS route but failed. If you are using Wordpress the easiest way would be to place 2 columns in the section you want the division. then place one element in each and then target their HTML codes accordingly.